# Microsoft Azure SQL Database Trace Replay

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'd like to make a direct comparison of a physical server to a serverless Azure SQL environment by using an hour snapshot of all SQL Server activity from some existing infrastructure.

Is it possible to use the SQL Server Profiler to record trace data and replay this on an Azure SQL instance?  I am not attempting to tweak or performance tune the existing system, but want to compare how an Azure server at various tiers will perform that workload.

Another option might be to use the **SQL Server Distributed Replay** functionality if this is an option in Azure.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server profiler and Distributed Replay are not available.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/431943-profiler-for-sql-azure

You may want to try SQL Workload Profiler.

https://cbailiss.wordpress.com/sql-workload-profiler/

SQL Azure Managed Instances will soon have SQL Profiler available:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uT46lpjeQE&feature=youtu.be&t=1415

Answer (score 1):

your entire question boils down to how can i choose the correct tier  in sql azure for my on premises instances..

As alberto points out,there is no way to handle this now directly,for now you can use below workaround

go to http://dtucalculator.azurewebsites.net/    and download powershell script and schedule it  for some duration and upload the generated log files to azure website.Once done, you will be provided with chart like below ..
[image]

References:
https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-sql-database-how-to-choose-the-right-service-tier/

Comment: Thanks, I have already run the DTU tool, it's fantastic!  This would be enough for me if it was my decision.  Some people are more risk-averse and want "proof" that this is valid....